# What is the meaning of a monomorphism in $S/X$ being "fiberwise"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, terminology, slice-category

**Notation**: $S$:the category of abstract sets; $S/X$: the slice category of $S$ over a set $X$; $A_x$: the fiber of a set $A$ over an element $x$ of the codomain of a function $A\rightarrow X$.

My question is the following: If $\alpha:f\rightarrow g$ is a monomorphism in $S/X$, what does it mean for it to be "fiberwise"? The question appears as exercise 2.43 in "Sets for Mathematics" by F.W. Lawvere and R. Rosebrugh and I have included it below for convenience's sake:

> An important case of slice categories (see Exercise 1.30(e)) is the category of X-indexed families of abstract sets $S/X$. Recall that in $S/X$ objects are mappings with codomain $X$ and arrows are commutative triangles. The name “family” arises as follows: For any object $f:A\rightarrow X$ of $S/X$ and any element $x:1\rightarrow X$ the inverse image of $x$ along $f$ is a part of A denoted $A_x$ and is called the “fiber of $A$ over x”, A is the “sum” of the family of all its fibers. This is a very simple example of a variable set.
>
> 1. Show that the category $S/X$ has binary sums that are computed “fiberwise”.
> 2. Show that monomorphisms in $S/X$ are also “fiberwise” and
>    have characteristic morphisms taking values in the object $\Omega$ of $S/X$,
>    which has each fiber equal to $2$.

I understand that a monomorphism in $S/X$ precisely corresponds to an injective function that respects the fiber-structure induced on the domain by morphisms into $X$. Further more, if $f:A'\rightarrow X$ and $g:A''\rightarrow X$ then given any element $x\in X$,

$$\alpha A'_x \subseteq A''_x$$

This implies that in order to specify a monomorphism in $S/X$, it involves for each fiber $A'_x$, choosing a 'part' of the fiber $A''_x$. Is that a correct interpretation of the adjective "fiberwise"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $A\stackrel f \to X$ and $B\stackrel g \to X$, for every morphism $\alpha\colon A\to B$ in $S/X$ and every element $x\colon 1\to X$, there is a commuting diagram as below.

$\hskip2in$[image: Commuting diagram]

The leftmost map $\alpha_x$ exists thanks to the universal property of the lower square, combined with the commutativity of the upper square and the rightmost triangle (notice that we need not use the universality of the upper square).

The usual terminology is that a property is *fibrewise* when it holds on $\alpha$ if and only if it holds on $\alpha_x$ for all $x$.

Now, consider the property of being a monomorphism. Since the top square is a pull-back, $\alpha$ being a monomorphism implies that $\alpha_x$ is also a monomorphism, for all $x$.

Conversely, if $\alpha$ is not a monomorphism, in particular it is not an injective map of sets over $X$, and there is an $x$ for which the corresponding $\alpha_x$ is not injective.

In conclusion, we can *check* the property of being a monomorphism on the fibres - this is the meaning of being fibrewise.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the diagram  in the response commutes for any arbitrary morphism in $S/X$. What did the authors then refer specifically to monomorphisms being fiberwise?

Comment: @jaspreet I edited my answer adding further details. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanatory edit. It helped me so much.

Comment: @jaspreet Glad to help! I recommend also "Conceptual Mathematics" by Stephen Schanuel and William Lawvere.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Naturally, I started with that book. Although I find the intuitive presentation great in that book (and perhaps definitely required for understanding), but I much prefer this book's presentation which seems more structured and axiomatic, as I have long struggled with doubts about what construction is and is not allowed in a proof in a given context.


I guess, my ideal book would be something that provides intuitive understanding (perhaps something helps build a picture of some kind in my mind), and also provide a nice theory.

Comment: @jaspreet In such case, I would go for Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113991/discussion-between-jaspreet-and-aurelio).